# Magento MagMI Importer Help needed

Tags: magento, magmi

I have a set of data in a database, which I can export to any format via script.

My issue is I need to do the following (I have all of the data and imagery ready to go)

-Import Products
-Import their associated images (up to 8 in the set)
-Import categories (3 or 4 levels) 
-Many products have variations (size, color, etc...) the variations have their own skus
-- Some products have more than one attribute that can be selected (Choose size, Choose color) each combination has its own sku
--- widget A has 5 colors and 5 sizes (25 skus)
- All products have 3 tiers of pricing

Will MagMI handle of all of this? If someone here has good experience with this please message me on skype "JoshMarthaller"  we may have a bit of work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Magmi will do all of these things.  For what you describe, you will need several plugins which are bundled with the core magmi product.  Configurables import, tier products import, image attributes processor, import categories sound like the ones you need.  They all work with csv files or using the datapump API (I've used all up to magento 1.7)